# Parent and Child Figures in Eclipse GEF

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-gef

How do you make one figure a child of another in a GEF applcation?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to GEF as well. Actually I am learning that currently.

But aren't all the `IFigure#add()` methods exactly what you want?